# Active Directory Authenticating through multple ou groups

Tags: c#, active-directory, ldap

I am trying to traverse our ldap path at the min obv dont want to share live details but here is some code I think i may have to loop our ou groups as they are in differernt folders when i look at the nodes, would any have idea how I would loop the ou groups using the below code I have already created.

```
string logintype = rbAuthenticationType.SelectedItem.Value.ToString();
if (logintype == "Domain")
  {
     string adPath = "LDAP://ipaddress/DC=companynamee"; //Path to your LDAP directory server
            LdapAuthentication adAuth = new LdapAuthentication(adPath);

          try
            {
                  if (true == adAuth.IsAuthenticated(txtDomain.Text, txtUserName.Text, txtPassword.Text))
                {
                    string groups = adAuth.GetGroups();

                   //Create the ticket, and add the groups.

                    FormsAuthenticationTicket authTicket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(1,
                              txtUserName.Text, DateTime.Now, DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(60), chkRememberMe.Checked, groups);

                    //Encrypt the ticket.
                    string encryptedTicket = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(authTicket);

                    //Create a cookie, and then add the encrypted ticket to the cookie as data.
                    HttpCookie authCookie = new HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, encryptedTicket);


                    //Add the cookie to the outgoing cookies collection.
                    Response.Cookies.Add(authCookie);

                    //You can redirect now.
                    Response.Redirect(FormsAuthentication.GetRedirectUrl(txtUserName.Text, false));
                }
                else
                {
                    lblerror.Text = "Authentication did not succeed. Check user name and password.";
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                lblerror.Text = "Error authenticating. " + ex.Message;
            }
}
```